# Intellij Profiler doesn't start

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiling

I'm running IntelliJ Idea 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition) on Ubuntu. When I want to start profiling (a java test) I am getting in the console this error

> [ERROR] Failed to initialize JfrSync class Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/jfr/FlightRecorderListener

Then, after the execution ends, the Profiler tab says: "Profiler error: there is no dump file".
My idea.log:

```
022-08-02 13:29:31,475 [    547]   INFO - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Using cached broken plugins file
2022-08-02 13:29:31,661 [    733]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 60 ms
2022-08-02 13:29:31,787 [    859]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-221.5080.210, 12 Apr 2022 05:32)
2022-08-02 13:29:31,788 [    860]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - OS: Linux (5.4.0-122-generic, amd64)
2022-08-02 13:29:31,856 [    928]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - JRE: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
2022-08-02 13:29:31,858 [    930]   INFO - #c.i.i.StartupUtil - JVM: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
.....................
2022-08-02 15:57:30,756 [ 125069]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=prj, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=/mypath/prj)Encoding took 28 ms, RunManager took 63 ms
2022-08-02 15:57:31,249 [ 125562]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appExportableFileTemplateSettings took 31 ms, FileTypeManager took 40 ms, FindSettings took 46 ms, SettingsSyncPlugins took 13 ms, XDebuggerSettings took 11 ms
2022-08-02 15:57:31,581 [ 125894]   INFO - #c.i.c.i.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS)
2022-08-02 15:57:31,860 [ 126173]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 288 ms to grab EDT for #update (com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorMarkupModelImpl$1)
2022-08-02 15:57:31,864 [ 126177]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 288 ms to grab EDT for #update (com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorMarkupModelImpl$1)
2022-08-02 15:57:32,825 [ 127138]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 581 ms to grab EDT for CodeWithMeUsersAction#update (com.jetbrains.rd.platform.codeWithMe.toolbar.CodeWithMeUsersAction)
2022-08-02 15:57:33,714 [ 128027]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /mypath/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/221.5080.210/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/pathToJvm/jdk1.8.0_331/lib/tools.jar
2022-08-02 15:57:34,562 [ 128875]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 18 ms, XDebuggerSettings took 17 ms
2022-08-02 15:57:34,588 [ 128901]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - KCRI storage is closed (didn''t exist)
2022-08-02 15:57:34,592 [ 128905]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader is closed (didn''t exist)
2022-08-02 15:57:34,811 [ 129124]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=prj, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=/mypath/prj)ProjectStartupSharedConfiguration took 11 ms, RunManager took 108 ms, VcsDirectoryMappings took 17 ms, VcsDirectoryRenames took 11 ms
2022-08-02 15:57:34,814 [ 129127]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.i.ActionUpdater - 218 ms to grab EDT for RunConfigurationsComboBoxAction#update (com.intellij.execution.actions.RunConfigurationsComboBoxAction)
2022-08-02 15:57:42,182 [ 136495]   INFO - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexService - initialized
2022-08-02 15:57:42,185 [ 136498]   WARN - #o.j.k.i.s.r.KotlinCompilerReferenceIndexStorage - kotlin-data-container is not found
2022-08-02 15:57:42,188 [ 136501]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - initialized
2022-08-02 15:57:42,189 [ 136502]   INFO - #c.i.c.b.CompilerReferenceServiceBase - backward reference index reader doesn''t exist
2022-08-02 15:57:42,246 [ 136559]   INFO - #c.i.c.i.CompilerUtil -  COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 10962 ms: 0 min 10sec
2022-08-02 15:57:42,844 [ 137157]   INFO - #c.i.c.s.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /mypath/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/221.5080.210/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/pathToJvm/jdk1.8.0_331/lib/tools.jar
2022-08-02 15:57:43,034 [ 137347]   INFO - #c.i.p.u.a.AsyncProfilerConfigurationExtensionBase - start profiler from run configuration, add VM parameters: -agentpath:/tmp/libasyncProfiler.so=start,jfr,event=cpu,interval=1ms,jfrsync=profile,file=/mypath/_profiler/MySpringITClass.jfr
2022-08-02 15:59:11,413 [ 225726]   INFO - #c.i.p.u.a.AsyncProfilerProcess - notifyStateChangedAsync: com.intellij.profiler.api.Attached@b3ae692 -> com.intellij.profiler.api.ReadingData@73077c5e
2022-08-02 15:59:11,429 [ 225742]   INFO - #c.i.p.u.a.AsyncProfilerProcess - notifyStateChangedAsync: com.intellij.profiler.api.ReadingData@73077c5e -> com.intellij.profiler.api.ProfilerError@47982261
```

Comment: Is it possible to share full idea.log after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: Is there any particular part you are interested in?

Comment: Yes, startup information with IDE configuration.